# Single-band, 5GHz only WiFi router?

Tags: wifi, wireless, router

Are there any consumer-priced, **single**-band (5GHz / 802.11ac only) WiFi routers, i.e., ones that *only* have a 5GHz radio?

Comment: Do you mean one that you can disable the 2.4GHz radio? Or do you need one for whatever reason that doesn't include a 2.4GHz radio at all?

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. I mean one's that only have a 5GHz radio and lack a 2.4GHz radio.

Comment: @Geremia, Having no 2.4Ghz radio would break backwards compatibility with b/g/n WiFi. Any router that has only a 5Ghz radio in it cannot receive a [WiFi Certification](https://www.wi-fi.org/certification)! (Then it's not a "WiFi" device at all!) That's basically shooting yourself in the foot for compatibility with most WiFi devices. Of course you can usually disable the 2.4 Ghz radio in a router that *has* one...

Comment: @Romen That's what I thought; it's for backwards compatibility. Perhaps you can turn your comment into an answer. I didn't know about WiFi Certification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Routers and WiFi devices have to undergo [certification](https://www.wi-fi.org/certification) to have the "WiFi" branding. Any router that does not have a 2.4 Ghz radio would not be backwards compatible with [IEEE 802.11 b/g/n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11) and may not qualify for the "WiFi" branding.

I have never seen a "WiFi" router with only a 5 Ghz radio. But you can disable the 2.4 Ghz radio in many routers though. It is possible that a router with only 802.11ac support can exist, but it may be hard to find a product like that using the "WiFi" brand as a search term.

For now, I would not recommend seeking out a product that explicitly avoids having a 2.4 Ghz radio. It wouldn't be guaranteed to work with other WiFi devices unless it was WiFi certified too. Some day the WiFi Alliance may decide to deprecate the 2.4 Ghz standards and this answer may no longer be correct.

Comment: Is there an estimate of how many devices use still use 802.11 b, g, or n or simply don't support ac?

Comment: I can't say for b or g, but n is *definitely* supported by every device made today. With 5 Ghz you get high bandwidth but trade off range and penetration. 2.4 Ghz cannot be completely replaced by 5 Ghz for all use-cases so 802.11n and 2.4 Ghz will be sticking around for now.

Comment: Oh, yes, higher frequency can't penetrate barriers as well.

Comment: WiFi is one thing, IEEE 802.11 is something different. If the device works up to the 802.11 it does not need to have the branding.

Comment: @JanDorniak, I made sure that my answer doesn't conflate those two things. My answer carefully points out that the "WiFi" certification is required for assurance of compatibility because IEEE doesn't do anything to guarantee compatibility for end-users. To me, a "WiFi" device is specifically a device that is certified by the WiFi Alliance. You absolutely can make a 802.11 compliant device that only has a 5 Ghz radio, it just wouldn't be a "WiFi" device.

Comment: @Romen that's true. Although I personally would use equipment where a trusted vendor states it supports 802.11, they cannot use Wi-Fi branding. And 802.11n works on both 2.4GHz and 5GHz. Where did you get the info that a device without 2.4 GHz would fail the certification?

Comment: @JanDorniak, 7 years of working in computer retail and I have never seen a product with the "WiFi" badge not have 2.4Ghz b g or n support. I will edit the answer if that statement was not true, but I cannot find anything that contradicts it.

Comment: @Romen well, that they are not made does not mean they are not allowed by standards and the alliance. They don't make sense commercially, as consumers products - I'll give you that. But stating it as a fact just because you never saw them working in retail which usually doesn't have the more "unusual" devices is kind of overreaching. And standards usually allow far more things that what's sold to consumers.

Comment: @JanDorniak, Updated the answer with less matter-of-fact phrasing.

Comment: @Romen upvoted. And while I don't believe 2.4 will deprecated in the coming decades, it remains to be seen. My reason is that a lot of IoT and other devices are price sensitive and 2.4 hardware is less expensive. Just look at mobile data: 2G outlived 3G.